# PL/SQL Procedures/Functions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a function `invoiceCheck` with one input parameter (invoice number) to check if the invoice exists in my database.

```
Create or replace function invoiceCheck(invoice_number_text IN
char)
 RETURN char IS
invoice_id_text invoices.invoice_id%type;
invoice_total_text invoices.invoice_total%type;
invoice_due_date_text invoices.invoice_due_date%type;
BEGIN
select invoice_total
into invoice_total_text
from invoices
where invoices.invoice_number=invoice_number_text ;
return invoice_total_text;
END;
```

I also wrote a procedure `InvoiceDetail` that has one input parameter (invoice number).  In the procedure, I called the function `invoiceCheck` to check if the invoice exists and if yes I want to display the `invoice_id`, `invoice_total` and `invoice_due_date` for that invoice. If not, I want to print out a message `“invoice not in the database”` from my procedure. Here is my procedure:

```
Create or replace procedure InvoiceDetail(invoice_number_text IN
char) IS
exist_invoice_number char;
invoice_total_text invoices.invoice_total%type;
invoice_id_text invoices.invoice_id%type;
invoice_due_date_text invoices.invoice_due_date%type;
BEGIN
select count(*) into exist_invoice_number from invoices
where invoices.invoice_id = invoice_id_text;
if exist_invoice_number is not null  then
invoice_id_text := invoiceCheck(invoice_number_text);
 invoice_total_text := invoiceCheck(invoice_number_text);
 invoice_due_date_text := invoiceCheck(invoice_number_text);
dbms_output.put_line('Invoice ID:' ||invoice_id_text);
 dbms_output.put_line('Invoice Total:' ||invoice_total_text);
 dbms_output.put_line ( 'Invoice Due Date:' || invoice_due_date_text);
else
 dbms_output.put_line('Invoice not in the database');
end if;
END;
```

When I go to execute an invoice number-QP58872 using:

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
execute InvoiceDetail('QP58872');
```

I'm getting this error

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: please never ever use deprecated `char` data type, use variable-length`varchar2` data type instead.

Comment: this should be problematic : `... count(*) into exist_invoice_number...` from number returning to char. By the way `invoice_total` in `invoice_total_text invoices.invoice_total%type` may be numeric column but should be of string type.

Comment: Hi, just for know, what type is invoice_total column in invoices? is a char, a varchar, a number?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito invoice_total is type number while invoice_number is varchar2

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I tried varchar2 in the procedure but it gives me compilation errors.

Comment: the problem is returning numeric values to string or reverse. ( I only suggested you to use varchar2 instead of char wherever you use )